# Assign Firestore JSON object to a variable in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore I have a "employee" node that looks like that :

[image]

I'm asigning that node to a "User" object in Kotlin:

```
object User {
    val firstName: String = "";
    val lastName: String = "";
    val employeeId:String="";
    val city:String = "";
    val email:String="";
    val salary:Number=0;
    val imgUrl:String="";
    val employmentStatus:String="";
    val employmentDate: ??????
}
```

My question is what type should "employmentDate" be? In Typescript I'm doing just:

```
employmentDate:{day:number,month:number,year:number}
```

can I do something similar in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `object`. `object` are singleton classes in kotlin. Instead use normal classes in kotlin and use composition.

```
class User{
val firstName: String = "";
val lastName: String = "";
val employeeId:String="";
val city:String = "";
val email:String="";
val salary:Number=0;
val imgUrl:String="";
val employmentStatus:String="";
var employmentDate: EmploymentDate = EmploymentDate()

class EmploymentDate{
val day:Int=0
val month:Int=0
val year:Int=0
}
}
```

Comment: -ty sir  well I want to be able to call "User.firstName" from anywhere in my aplication and get firstName tha has been assign from firestore so I need a object/singelton for that - thank you again for a code above (y)

Comment: You can store it in shared preferences or create a custom singleton class wrapper around it.

Comment: could You please clearified  " custom singleton class wrapper around it" - like You said object is like a singeltone in kotlin so that's what I just did ,I put my User in a singeltone-guessing I am missunderstanding something here...:S

Comment: `object MySingleton {
    lateinit var myUser: User

}
/*
Somewhere after getting the data from the FireStore
 */
MySingleton.myUser=user `
After this you can access using your singleton class anywhere.

Comment: great -  now I uderstand -that was to big help sig -ty (y)